# Codeigniter nested query in cycle

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a site devloped in codeigniter where I'd want to create a query with some condition and a condition inside with OR like this:

```
Select * from users where username = 'user' and nation_id = 90 and active = 1 and (rate = 1 OR rate = 2 OR rate = 3);
```

Now I have create this code but isn't working because is like writing this:

```
Select * from users where username = 'user' and nation_id = 90 and active = 1 and rate = 1 OR rate = 2 OR rate = 3;
```

I don't want this query but the first. This is my code:

```
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where('username', 'user');
$this->db->where('nation_id', 90);
$this->db->where('active', 1);

for ($i = 1; $i<=3; $i++){
     $this->db->or_where('rate', $i);
}

$query = $this->db->get();
```

Please don't tell me other way like write the query manually because I have simplified it and is where huge to make a manual query.
The cycle is important that is in that way because I have to cycle an array for example.
I only want to insert my or condition inside a `()` is possible?

Comment: What do you get from $this->db->last_query() ? And, you do notice that you're selecting * from `service`...not from `users`, right?

Comment: error of copy because I have many query similar.. @jcorry

Comment: Looks like you could use `BETWEEN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$this->db->where_in()`, like for example:

```
$opts = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <=3; $i++) {
    $opts[] = $i;
}
$this->db->where_in('rate', $opts);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `where_in` method for this:

```
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where('username', 'user');
$this->db->where('nation_id', 90);
$this->db->where('active', 1);
$this->db->where_in('rate' array(1, 2, 3))
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Or, you can do the same thing with the `and_where` method and explicitly setting the brackets:

```
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where('username', 'user');
$this->db->where('nation_id', 90);
$this->db->where('active', 1);
// This produces: AND (rate = 1 OR rate = 2 OR rate = 3)
$this->db->where('(rate = 1 OR rate = 2 OR rate = 3)')
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: No I have to use a cycle for the or_where condition

Comment: Accidentally used the `or_where` method rather than `and_where`.

Comment: Sorry but I have to use cycle.. but your function can works in other case +1

Comment: Just curios: why so much upvotes with even loop requirment not met?

Comment: @Cthulhu Perhaps because upvoters didn't expect writing a simple loop is needed to mark the answer as valid, this is obvious, at least for a `5k` user.

Comment: My question is explicit: "I have to use the cycle".. well isn't the valid answer @HashemQolami

Answer (score 1):

With the `BETWEEN` operator, you don't have to have a loop :

```
$this->db->where("rate BETWEEN 1 AND 3");
```

This method is cleaner, since if you make it between 1 and 150, you won't have a huge sql query : `rate IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... , 149, 150)` but just `rate BETWEEN 1 AND 150`. That seems much more fitted.

Comment: No I need the condition to use with a cycle

Comment: I really don't understand why here, unless you do some testing in your loop that would give a query like `rate IN (1, 3, 7, 9)`